# Scrollbars stick on top while entire page is scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, scrollbar, anchor

The webpage I'm working on has a link to an anchor and an anchor (pretty simple case).

The link is something like :

```
    <a href="#target">Link</a>
```

And the anchor is something like :

```
    <a name="target">Anchor</a>
```

When I click on the Link, the entire page is scrolling to the Anchor : OK
However, the vertical scrollbar seems to not be affected by that scrolls, it remains on top : KO

So basically, once I clicked on link, and once the page has been scrolled down, there is no way to go back up to the top thanks to the scrollbar.

I know that some jQuery is used on that webpage but not for that purpose. I guess they are some jQuery sideeffects but I don't know how to find/debug it.

I'm also afraid that some Css are causing some troubles.

Guys if you have any ideas how to debug it, please let me know !

Cheers !

Yann

Comment: We can't debug the code,,,because you haven't provided it.

Comment: Well I'm not looking for some code corrections, but a way to debug it.

Do you have any ideas of what can cause the scrollbar to stick on top while all the rest is "moving" ? I know this is a pretty open question...

Comment: So your code is wrong but you don't want us to debug it for you just tell you have to find the errors...is that it?

Comment: The thing is this website is really badly coded, meaning they are thousands of lines of code for nothing. I can't copy everything here. (And I guess I'm not allowed).

For some reason I believe that they aren't thousand ways to deal with scrollbars. Obviously someone has coded something wrong on that website. I need to know how I can detect it ? I need to know a good method of debuging.

Comment: As you can see above (after editing my post), the link and the anchor are very simple, I'm 99% that the problem is not coming from that but from some external scripts (Jquery or maybe some sideeffect of Css attributes ont elements).

Comment: Google would be your friend but if you don't know what's wrong with something how could you tell if the debug tools was finding the right error. There is no debug tool that can know how the site **should** work. As far as it's concerned, the code does what it's told.

Comment: Maybe you do not scroll but only move two nested DIVs. Like a vertical slideshow. The page is still at the top but the inner DIV is scrolled down.

Comment: YannM, As @Paulie_D stated, without your code, the only thing we can do is guess and we can keep on guessing for a while (ages) without providing a solution. It would be much easier and less time consuming if you provided us the necessary elements so we can help you efficiently. Provide a link to an online example and post the code you belive the issue is comming from here.

Comment: Maybe I explained it the wrong way. For sure there is a bug somewhere in the code. I totally agree with you. I'm not asking you to provide me a correction. I'm asking you if you know a way to find easily the part of code that's wrong. This is a very large project, 10years old, so you can imagine all the horrors I'm facing. I tried to find some code about "windows.scrollbars" or some event listenner linked to a tag, but so far it didn't help. Do you know any other way to interact with scrollbars ?

Answer (score 0):

Check what element is actually being scrolled and which element has the scroll bar.

Comment: Are you familiar with debugger tools in all the major browsers? I suggest Chrome and hit f12.

Comment: I try to use http://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2, but no event seems to be attached to the link.

Comment: Ok guys I've found part of the answer : There is an iframe showing the exact same page in the "main page" (kind of "page-ception" ahah). I don't know if you follow me. Because of some CSS, the main page is not displayed but only the content of the iframe. So basically, when the user click on the link, this is not the window which is scrolling but the content of the iframe.